# Add NuGet package without its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am sure many of us have run into this issue and somehow i am having problems getting resolution anywhere.

I have a shared library (Common.Infrastructure.dll) across many projects and I am using TeamCity built in NuGet Server to host this library. This library internally relies on NuGet packages such as Fluent Nhibernate, Log4net, StructureMap, etc).

Quite simply, doing a "Install-Package Common.Infrastructure" in a project that needs this shared dependency also adds Fluent NHibernate, log4net, SM and so on) as "references" to the project. I am not going to use these dependencies of Common.Infrastructure directly, but would obviously need them in the output (bin/debug) folder eventually.

Is there a way to not have these dependencies referenced with built in nuget (nuspec) support?

Answer (score 73):

The Install-Package command has a flag to ignore the dependencies. Example:

```
Install-Package Common.Infrastructure -IgnoreDependencies
```

Comment: Your answer will work, but you really missed the point: how to create a package without dependencies (as Jeff mentioned below). I'm sure this package are going to be widely used by many developers in his company, so none of them will remember (or even know) that this specific package should be installed using the "-IgnoreDependencies".key

Answer (score 9):

*Please note, his actual question is about how to create a package that doesn't add dependencies, not how to install a package without its dependencies.*

Using Nuspec you can explicit control which packages are dependencies and which assemblies in your package are referenced by the target project.  However, I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you are asking with NuGet because there is no way to indicate to Visual Studio that an assembly should be copied to the bin directory without adding it as a project reference.

I think your problem is rather a symptom of lumping too much functionality into a single assembly.  I recommend you split your Common.Infrastructure.dll into separate assemblies for the various aspects of functionality.  Something like:

- Common.Infrastructure.Logging.dll - depends on Log4net
- Common.Infrastructure.Database.dll - depends on Fluent Nhibernate
- Common.Infrastructure.IoC.dll - depends on StructureMap
- Whatever other sub assemblies are appropriate
- Common.Infrastructure.dll - a new smaller core of functionality that depends only on the framework

Of course, the exact set of assemblies you break it down into will depend on what functionality is in Common.Infrastructure.dll and how you use it. Once you have separate packages for each of these assemblies, then you can choose which ones to reference in a given project and limit it to the aspects and dependencies that you really need.

Answer (score -3):

There is solution on this.

Edit your nuspec file and add a reference dll only which you want. 
references
reference file="dllwhichyouwantToreference.dll" references

Comment: 3 down votes and not a single explanation. I don't think it helps us. Will the downvoters please explain why ?

Comment: I have just spent SIX DAYS unpicking this. The problem with this, and actually the original question, is that nuget has no way of knowing that this reference will actually conflict with a dll from a nuget package that installs that same file. 

The problem with this is that when you go to update the nuget package in the consuming app, it can be over-written with an old version. Which trust me, leads to pulling hair out.

Devs then stop maintaining the shared code, copy snippets out, make breaking changes without updating dependents. Leading to a poor, unsuspecting dev losing six days.